# How can i read data running batch file and store in a text file?

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, nuodb

I am running a command in a command prompt it is a nuodb manager

```
nuodbmgr --broker localhost --password bird123 --command "log database madhu categories sql-statements"
```

this will get all running tasks in nuodb server. after getting more data its clean up old data now i want to store hole data into one file this file can be new file for every day. how can i write batch file or any alternative way to do this requirement plz help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
nuodbmgr --broker localhost --password bird123 --command "log database madhu categories sql-statements" > sometextfile.txt
```